# Limit jQuery pop ups?

Tags: jquery

So I have his code that pops up a new window to my advertisement code, however it does it every time `<body>` is clicked which is what I wanted, but I'm wanting to limit it to 2 pop ups per page ?

```
        <script>
        function openInNewTab(url) {
          var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
          win.focus();
        }
        </script>

        <body onclick="openInNewTab('https://example.com/advertisement.html');">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Then you'll need to learn how to use Local Storage to track the number of opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not work in the snippet because of sessionStorage and body, but here is a simple implementation:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Content<p>
        <script>
            const openInNewTab = (url) => {
              /* Here you init a poup */
              alert(`Open ${url} trigered`);
            }

            const handleBodyClick = () => {
              let totalOpened = Number( sessionStorage.getItem('totalOpened') );
              
              if (totalOpened < 2) {
                openInNewTab('https://example.com/advertisement.html');
                totalOpened = totalOpened + 1;
                sessionStorage.setItem('totalOpened', totalOpened);
              }
              
              if (totalOpened === 2) {              
                /* This is imporant for performance */
                document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleBodyClick);
              }
            }

            document.body.addEventListener('click', handleBodyClick);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`sessionStorage` works per browser tab so if you want to open ads per tab you should use this, but if want it to work globally (for the domain) you can replace `sessionStorage` with `localStorage` - it's a storage for the subdomain.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted I just removed the alert with a var url.